# Get the row number of a named Excel cell in MATLAB

Tags: excel, matlab

I'm working with a quite big Excel file in MATLAB with the `xlsread` function. I'm particularly interested in a named cell, let's say it's called FIRST_DATA. So in MATLAB I call:

`[num, txt, raw] = xlsread(filename,sheet,'FIRST_DATA')`

But I'm not interested in the data that this cell contains, but in the number of the row of this cell. How can I get this information?

My first guess is reading the data in the cell first, then reading the whole sheet and finally searching the resulting matrix for the cell data to find the row. But I hope for a more convenient way or one with less effort.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: If the named cell is defined inside Excel, I'm not sure that you can get the row number through `xlsread`. Try the methods of `actxserver('Excel.Application')`

Comment: it works, I'll post the "how to" as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way using [ActiveX](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/using-a-matlab-application-as-an-automation-client.html), as suggested by [Adiel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2514793/adiel) in the Comments. Code example:

```
excelapp = actxserver('Excel.Application');
workbook = excelapp.Workbooks.Open('myspreadsheet.xlsx');
worksheet = workbook.Sheets.Item('sheet_with_data');
worksheet.Activate;
row_number = worksheet.Range('FIRST_DATA').Row;
Close(workbook);
Quit(excelapp);
delete(ExcelApp);
```

You should be closing everything properly to to prevent potential memory leaks.

Comment: Great that you found the solution!